# Multiple UIBarButtonItems actions not calling

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I Have created two BarButtonItems and added to the rightbarbutton, first bar button action only calling, second bar button action not calling, can any one help me

```
let saveBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: .Done, target: self, action: #selector(saveClicked(_:)))
let addVitalBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: #selector(addVital(_:)))
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([addVitalBarButton,saveBarButton], animated: true)
```

only addVitalBarButton action calling, if I changed the items order

```
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([saveBarButton,addVitalBarButton], animated: true)
```

the above case only saveBarButtonAction calling

```
func saveClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("SaveClicked selected ")
}
func addVital(sender: UIBarButtonItem){
    print("Add vital selected")
}
```

For left bar button I added, it is working fine, In right bar button only it is not calling
can any one help me figure out why the second bar button action is not calling?

Comment: I'm not getting any problems. 

1. Is your viewcontroller part of a UINavigationController?
2. Try using ```#selector(ViewController.saveClicked(_:))``` instead

Comment: I tried  `ViewController.saveClicked(_:)` but it is not calling

Comment: The code is working fine on my side. Also @Ronak's code is ok.

Comment: what is the name of your view controller?

Comment: view controller name is VitalMonitoringViewController

Comment: @RajuAbe in that case, do ```#selector(VitalMonitoringViewController.saveClicked(_:))``` instead of ```#selector(saveClicked(_:))```

Comment: @RonakShah I tried the above solution, but it's not calling

Comment: Share your project link if possible.

Comment: @RajuAbe Have you try like this `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [addVitalBarButton,saveBarButton]`

Comment: @NDoc Yes, I tried this approach